# distribute php files remotely from my own site to the client's own website

Tags: php, api

If I am understanding correctly, it is possible not to give your code to the client by having your client connect to your web server and accesses (Only) the PHP source codes without the ability to see or edit them. I mean is just changing all of your links to the PHP files would resolve the problem or is the process way more complicated? I understand that API [which I do not know much about] would be the best solution, but how do I link these two servers together? and if it is possible to do so, can i do the same for my HTML/Javascript files?

Comment: If the PHP files are on your server, why don't you just host the whole website?

Comment: You could obfuscate the source using something like ionCube

Comment: @BenEverard ionCube and other encoders can be easily decoded. The php interpreter needs to be able to run those files somehow.

Comment: obfuscating the source code doesn't prevent the client to distribute the files...

Answer (score 0):

I'd package all my source files (including HTML/JS) in a .zip and have your client download that instead then unzip it onto their own server.

Ideally you want to use FTP instead, faster and safer.

Comment: but doesn't unzipping a zipped file enables you to retrieve the content? Sorry if I am not understanding you well...

Comment: if you zip all your source files then when unzipped it will contain all of your source files.